# good data visual package for unix?

Tags: log-files, visualization, graphics

Quite often I'm looking a large blocks of data (logs files) looking for oddities in timing from processes.  While I can convert this to an .csv/tab file easy enough, I have issues trying to render it in a graph in unix.

Many packages such as rrd are good, but are specific usage based.

Does anyone know of a good open source package to generate an image(s) of data?

Not too much programming wanted:

Features wanted: 3d plots, histograms, variation (stddev_pop), etc..

The data set isn't that large, probably < 1 million lines ever.

Answer (score 1):

In the free-as-in-beer, free-as-in-speech category I've been using [SciDAVis](http://scidavis.sourceforge.net/) on and off over the years and it's always worked well. It's cross-platform and speedy. The UI has some quirks that require getting used to but all-in-all it's a very powerful plotting, graphing and graphical analysis program.

Answer (score 1):

R stats package has very powerful graphing and plotting and data file manipulation all as primitives. On top of that it is a full features stats package like SAS and a programming language as well. R is supported well on Windows/Mac/Linux and comes with an interactive console window. It's really all you will ever need.

My usual workflow is to do some data reformatting and reduction in python first because its easier for me and then feed this into fairly simple R scripts

[R project site](http://www.r-project.org/)

Comment: +1 for R! It's my stock tool for this kinda thing

Answer (score 0):

[R](http://www.r-project.org) has some nice plotting capabilities. It's reasonably easy to use and I'd recommend it.

[gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info) is good too.

[Processing](http://www.processing.org) has some beautiful looking visuals in their gallery but that looks like more programming that you want to do.

I've found all of these tools hard to get started with because they are not Excel. Once you get over the initial terror and learn the quirks then they are not so bad. It's a little like your first day using vi.

See also Wikipedia's category [Linux Graph Plotting Software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Linux_graph_plotting_software)